# add single button on cardview page

Tags: java, android, xml

created layout with radio button  in a cardview.
needed a single button at bottom but button is repeating with radio button.

below is the code for card view and design

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">


        <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/radiogrp_surveyoptions"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">


            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/rd_option1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text=""
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:textSize="15dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                />
</LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:gravity="center"
android:layout_weight="0.3">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_saveans"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:background="@drawable/buttonclick"
    android:text="Save"
    android:textColor="@color/whitecolor"
    android:textSize="15dp"
    android:foregroundGravity="bottom"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

please guide how i can add only one button after repeated cardview

Comment: are you using recyclerview for that? if yes than why are you keeping your button in the adapter?

Comment: Keep your button in the Activity Instead and perform operations using interface

Comment: new to android please guide how to keep that button outside the adapter.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of inflating layout containing both `CardView` and `Button`, for every element in the list, you should move `Button` to whatever layout you're inflating in `onCreate()` method. (or `onCreateView()` if you're using fragments)

So, assuming you're using `RecyclerView`, move `Button` to the layout containing your `<RecyclerView>` component.